# Hide items in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have tried to hide items in a custom list adapter. I can hide the visibility of the text but I cannot hide the whole list item. It still shows the dividers etc. I have tried:

```
tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

When I use the convertView i get a null pointer exception.

Comment: You can remove the item instead of hiding and, in the similar way, add the item to the list instead of showing. I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: i think this is not the best solution for this purpose. just try to set your specific condition and increase your position number in getView.

Answer (score 11):

1. You can set ContentView with No Element.

   In getView() of Your Custom Adapter.

   ```
   if(condition)
   {
     convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_null,null);
     return convertView;
   }
   else
   {
      convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_content,null);
      return convertView;
   }
   ```
2. your XML row_null.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 ways to do this:

1. Remove the items from your list inside or outside the adapter.
   Inside the adapter you can do it in the Constructor.

   `private List<String> list;
   public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
       list.remove(0);
       list.remove(1);
       list.remove(<whateverPositionYouLike>);
       this.list = list;
   }`
2. You need to figure out how many items you want to hide and need to build a similar logic.

`@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // In this adapter, we are supposed to hide the first item of the list view
        // Returning 0 if no of items are already 0
        if(list.size() <=1)
            return 0;
        // if number of items are more than one, returning one item less
        return list.size() - 1;
    }`

`@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // skipping the position
        return list.get(position + 1);
    }`

`

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {

    // this is important, as we are supposed to skip the first item of listview
    final int localPosition = position +1;

    ViewHolderItem holder;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolderItem();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderItem) v.getTag();
    }
    return v;
    }
```

`

3. Answer provided by @hims_3009

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in the way you are trying to, you'll need to use a custom Adapter and implement in there the logic for showing/not showing a line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide a row in a listview, you need to delete data in that position. For example if you use array adapter and want to hide the row on 5. position. You have to delete line from your array and the call notifyDatasetChanged() method.

(You can delete data from array by using tempArray)

or use this way

```
private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();    
// make list a new array, clearing out all old values in it.
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  if((i != 5)  && (i != 6)){        
   // if k = 5 or 6, dont add those items to the list
     items.add(something[i]);   /// whatever your list items are.
   }
}

ArrayAdapter<String> itemList = new
ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.itemlistlayout);
setListAdapter(itemlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide an entire item you need to build some logic into your getView() method to make it skip over various parts of your data.

lets say you have an ArrayAdapter and I want to hide the data that is at index 2. Your getView() method could look something like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup, parent){
    View mView = convertView;
    //TODO: Check if convertView was null, and inflate
    //      or instantiate if needed.

    //Now we are going to set the data
    mTxt = mView.findViewById(R.id.mTxt);
    if(pos >= 2){
        //If position is 2 or above, we ignore it and take the next item.
        mTxt.setText(this.getItem(pos + 1).toString()); 
    }else{
        //If position is below 2 then we take the current item.
        mTxt.setText(this.getItem(pos).toString());
    }
    return mView;
}
```

Note that this example is generalized, it is not meant to be able to be dropped directly into your project. I had to make assumptions about some things which I don't know the truth on. You can use the same concept as I've shown here though and modify it to your situation to be able to "hide" rows in your ListView.

Comment: this wont work as this will just show the next item twice

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a custom list adapter you can just call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter and the adapter itself has of course to implement the logic to filter out the views for the rows you want to hide. These are the methods that come to my mind that need to reflect that logic:

```
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        // here goes your logic to hide a row
```

Additionally you might have to change getItemId() as well.

Comment: I have tried this    lst.size();
System.out.println("SIZE: " + lst.size());
for(int count=0; count<lst.size(); count++)
{
  if(!str.contains("/2/"))
 {
    tv.setText("");
    lst.remove(count);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

Comment: The problem now is that is that it will delete from the list but not all that should be deleted

Comment: Your question is about hiding items, now you're talking about deleting items which are two different things. Please update your question to make clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also when you write "it will delete from the list but not all that should be deleted" you need to describe what is deleted and what should be deleted, and post the according code so that others can understand

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a much easier / safer solution: you just have to "embed" your item in a Layout, and change the visibility of this parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Embed ListView Item into a "parent" Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- This is the normal content of your ListView Item -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="World" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your code just do:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.my_listview_item, null);
    }
    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    if (shouldDisplayItem(position)) {
        parentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        parentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return view;
}
```

This way you always use/reuse the same item, and just hide/show it.