# How can i hide a listview item in android?

Tags: android, json, listview

Hi friends i have a listview and the contents are fetched from a webservice call. In that webservice call, there are fields like

```
 "OGType": "ORG" and  "OGType": "GROUP"
```

If click a button, the listview must shows the item having "OGType": "ORG", and hide the item having "OGType": "GROUP". Hope you understand what i meant. Please anyone help me for that. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: create custom adapter and do what you want in getView() method for more info see ( http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown )

Answer (score 1):

Try to set new data (only with ORG) to adapter and then call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your `getView` Method in your `Adapter` Class. That's the header
`public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup, parent)`

There you can properly hide the element(s) you want, you know, using the method [setVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

For more help you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324059/hide-items-in-a-listview)

Comment: The setVisibility() method doesn't work probably because the views are already generated. You won't see the content of the listitem but you'll still see the blank listitem.

Comment: That depends of value, if you set with `GONE` you don't see any blank.

Comment: Check out the comments in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5043017/1239966

Comment: Yes, with `GONE` as I said. You deleted your first answer where you wanted to purge but OP just wants to hide and I think the list should be there and then filtered

Comment: I didn't delete any answer. It's still there. Secondly, from the comments in the answer : the strangest thing is, that it is the same behaviour for both visibilities :(

Answer (score 0):

The non hackish way will be to remove the items from your Collection which you use to generate the listview and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`;

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter and pass data to it in the form of Array or ArrayList (ArrayList is better when dealing with Custom Adapters). Whenever you need to add or remove the data from ListView, just add or remove the item to or from you ArrayList and call notifyDataSetChanged() on your custom adapter and it will update the ListView automatically.

In your case, whenever you click a button, edit you ArrayList and call your custom adapter's method called notifyDataSetChanged() and that's it. You'll see every time you call this method ListView will refresh itself if you have made any changes to the data. Hope it helps.

**NOTE - CUSTOM ADAPTER IS NOT COMPULSORY. ANY ADAPTER CAN BE USED e.g SimpleAdapter, ArrayAdapter etc.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a visible list and filters lists. You should use "visible" for complete the BaseAdpter as always, then, you can change the pointer of visible to other list (all, filter...)

Don't worry by the memory, are pointers, you only have each element only once.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private ArrayList<MyItem> visible;
   private ArrayList<MyItem> all;
   private ArrayList<MyItem> filter;

   public MyAdapter(ArrayList<MyItem> items) {
       all = items;
       visible = all; //Set all as visible
       filter = new ArrayList<Item>();
       for (Item i : items)
           if (i.getType().equals("ORG"))
               filter.add(i);

   }

   //Complete adapter using "visible"

   public void showOnlyOrg() {
      visible = filter;
      notifydatasetchanged();
   }
}
```