# Hide first item in listView Android

Tags: android, listview

I'm developing an Android project and I have tried to HIDE the first item in a listView of several ways:

1. If I put the next code, the space doesn't dissapear from the listView.

   > convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
2. If I put the next code, the item hides, but the next items appear into row of 2px height.

   > if(condition){
   >
   > convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(-1,1));
   >     convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   >
   > } else {
   >
   > if(convertView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
   >   
   >   convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   >   convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(-1,-2));
   >   
   >   }
   >   }

Somebody could help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324059/hide-items-in-a-listview)

Instead of setting the visibility to `GONE` set to it an empty layout

Answer (score 0):

there are three ways to do so;
1   use headview of listview  and control it;

2   add the itemlayout into a viewGroup,   take this viewGroup as convertView,and control the itemLayout visible or not by the position;

3  use viewType of adapter  by  different item layout

just ideas..

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to hide the first item in the adapter:

```
public class HideFirstItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List items;

    public RssListAdapter(Context context, List<RssEntry> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size() - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public RssEntry getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or even to store just a sublist in the constructor:

```
public RssListAdapter(Context context, List<RssEntry> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items.subList(1, items.size());
}
```

And keep the adapter as a normal one:
    ...
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

```
@Override
public RssEntry getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}
...
```